# Suddenly I'm not able to use sudo anymore

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

This happened on an up-to-date Ubuntu 20.04 system.

Since today, I cannot use `sudo` on my laptop anymore. I'm using a standard user account created after Ubuntu install. I do not remember if I edited `/etc/sudoers` to add my user account to be able to use `sudo`, or if I made myself a member of the `sudo` group. Today I am not a member of the `sudo` group. In fact, I am only a member of my own private group corresponding to my username and `lpadmin`.

Neither `/etc/group` nor `/etc/sudoers` has changed since I last was able to use `sudo`:

```
$ ls -l /etc/group
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1375 févr. 24 09:31 /etc/group

$ ls -l /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 root root 755 févr.  3  2020 /etc/sudoers
```

Is there any other way to configure `sudo` access that I might have used and which now has been undone?

I use `sudo` frequently to keep my system up to date. The last time was three days prior (I checked in `/var/log/auth.log`).

For example: `sudo` succeeds

```
Mar  5 16:25:55 MYMACHINE sudo: MYUSERNAME : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/MYUSERNAME ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/umount XXXXXXXXXXXX
Mar  5 16:25:55 MYMACHINE sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by MYUSERNAME(uid=0)
Mar  5 16:25:55 MYMACHINE sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Today `sudo` fails

```
Mar  8 17:16:12 MYMACHINE sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar  8 17:16:12 MYMACHINE sudo: MYUSERNAME : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=pts/16 ; PWD=/XXXX ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/mount XXXX
Mar  8 17:16:12 MYMACHINE sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar  8 17:16:28 MYMACHINE sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Mar  8 17:16:28 MYMACHINE sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [MYUSERNAME]
```

Since all my commands I executed with `sudo` are logged, I could verify that I didn't enter a stupid command that would lock me out of my machine.

One of my last actions where `sudo` succeeded was updating my system. The packages that were updated at that time were:

```
update-manager-core:amd64 (1:20.04.10.5, 1:20.04.10.6), dkms:amd64 (2.8.1-5ubuntu1, 2.8.1-5ubuntu2), nvidia-prime:amd64 (0.8.15.3~0.20.04.1, 0.8.16~0.20.04.1), libxnvctrl0:amd64 (440.82-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:20.04.10.5, 1:20.04.10.6), nvidia-settings:amd64 (440.82-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

My question is: How could this have happened?? The problem is easy enough to fix. My administrator account still exists and has `sudo`. But I would like to learn from this. Obviously, the possibility that my system has been hacked has come to my mind, but I prefer believing that it was user error on my part somewhere...

Comment: You aren't the only one, see [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239503/ubuntu-20-04-and-20-10-etc-securetty-no-such-file-or-directory). It contains a `/etc/securetty` file that you can use (or copy it from elsewhere).

Comment: I don't think this is related. I have the message about the missing securetty in my logs as far as they reach back, and this has never prevented me from using sudo. In my question I included that line as it occurred literally the same second as the relevant log entries. This is not a new install or upgrade. I have been using 20.04 for months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more digging I solved this - user error as I hoped it would be. Since `/etc/group` was changed on February 24th, I went back through my `auth.log` files and found this:

```
Feb 24 09:31:45 MYMACHINE sudo: MYUSERNAME : TTY=pts/17 ; PWD=/home/XXX ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/usermod -G lpadmin MYUSERNAME
```

Note the missing `-a` in the `usermod` command line. I unintentionally removed myself from all groups except `lpadmin` and my primary group.

I didn't notice anything until now, because I had not rebooted my computer until this weekend (always suspended and resumed). When I searched for stupid `sudo` commands typed earlier, I hadn't looked so far back. I did search for `usermod` commands in my `~/.bash_history` without success. That command must have been typed in a terminal window which had its history overwritten by another terminal closed later.